# How to get a global Object by Object name

Tags: node.js, meteor

In the meteor server.There is object like this:
A.js

```
testObject = function(){}
```

and I want to get `testObject`  by `testObject`'s name "testObject"

if "A.js" in Client . I know I can  get the Object by

```
var a = window["testObject"]
```

because of window is a global Object and save all other global Object.
but I don't know how to get it  in Server.
 Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Node or Browser?? - Global btw not Globe or globle...

Comment: @Nate I'm sorry for spelling mistakes

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to retain a global scope reference is just to wrap your code in an IIFE closure like this:

```
(function( namespace ) {
  console.log( namespace["testObject"] );
}( this ));
```

This will work on both server and client.

Comment: Great solution! It's a shame that Meteor (although I'm running an older version) wraps all files in an IIFE function automatically. Not a problem, just a bit unnecessary to add if there's already one in there.

Comment: Simply place those kinds of files in a `client/compatibility` file. Then it won't be wrapped in an IIFE and it will be run before other client files.

Answer (score 0):

just like node code. use like this

```
global["testObject"]
```

I get the answer on FreeNode .Thank you @bline